# Editing public/index.html in React

Tags: reactjs

I am building a website project in React and I need to add some code to the public/index.html file. the index.html file is empty and I cannot edit the file. Is this normal? I am using VS Code as an editor.

Comment: I am using VS Code as an editor.

Comment: How did you create your project? Create react app?

Comment: I did use Create react app

Comment: If you do this outside of your project folder `npx create-react-app my-app` the generated `public/index.html` will not be empty

Comment: I used npx create-react-app my-app to create the project yet the public/index.html file is empty.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not reproducible. I'll add an answer with the standard public/index.html maybe it helps.

Comment: To simply dismiss this as 'not reproducible' is very lazy. See my comment below. I reproduced the issue in another react app.

Comment: I am not trying to be lazy my friend. I repeat myself here, please add the steps I have to take to reproduce the error. Then I will do these steps. If it works for me, the issue is not reproducible

Comment: Steps I took that worked `npx create-react-app my-app` `cd my-app` `cat public/index.html` => prints what I posted as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using another IDE/Code editor
What are you using right now

Comment: This answer is as vague as the question :D also not helpful

Comment: I think my question is very specific.

Answer (score 0):

The default `my-app/public/index.html` after running `npx create-react-app my-app` should be

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know what it should be but I just created another npx create-react-app and reproduced the exact issue I originally started with.

Comment: We are missing some crucial step here, something is missing. I literally only ran the standard command already mentioned and this was the resulting `public/index.html` so I'll need something else. What are the needed steps to reproduce?

Comment: I agree; something is missing. Maybe a glitch with vscode. Maybe I should uninstall; this is weird.

Comment: What do you see in your terminal after running this in an empty folder `npx create-react-app my-app && cat my-app/public/index.html`?

Comment: if you see the content from the index.html then there is something wrong with the editor I propose

Comment: @JasonShumaker so? what is the output?

Comment: after running your command the editor created my-app and the output was the standard boilerplate html code for the index.html file

Comment: Awesome. So it was not an issue with vscode?